# how to generate a proxy class to a specific version of framework

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, proxy

I'm generating a proxy class of webservice to use in my project (offline work).

following instructions on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

like this for SVC:
C:\Temp\svc>svcutil "http://mywebservice.ws/wsAddress.asmx?WSDL"

like this for webservice:
C:\Temp\ws>wsdl "http://mywebservice.ws/wsAddress.asmx?WSDL"

Both are generated for version 4.0.

So it generates for .NET Framework version 4.0. An on my destination project I need to use it for Framework version 3.5.

When I copy the proxy class to the project and try to run it gives compilation error because some namespaces are not in v3.5 and I should use V3.5.

e.g. System.Threading.Tasks.Task  -> is not in V3.5

So How can I generate a proxy class for v3.5?

I'm using VS 2013.

Answer (score 2):

The [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN states:

> The tool does not support multi-targeting. If you want to generate a .NET 4 artifact from svcutil.exe, you have to use the svcutil.exe from the .NET 4 SDK. To generate a .NET 3.5 artifact, use the executable from the .NET 3.5 SDK.

so you just need to set up your environment to use the correct SDK before you call:

> C:\Temp\svc>svcutil "http://mywebservice.ws/wsAddress.asmx?WSDL"

If you don't have it, [download the .NET 3.5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3138)

Comment: Also is possible that you may find the SvcUtil tool version 3.0 at your machine in this location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin